# Need regexp for php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, yii2

```
    <?php foreach ($videos as $video): ?>


    <iframe width="420" height="345"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6t8GF30hs0E">
    </iframe>



<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Dont know how to do that,need your helps GUYS?
 Need to format https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6t8GF30hs0E
         to https://www.youtube.com/embed/6t8GF30hs0E
        Need Regex too convert watch?v= to embed/

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос задан на языке отличном от русского

Answer (score 4):

Зачем здесь `regexp`, если хватит обычного [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
$video = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed", $video);
```